# How to change the alignment of a tabularx within an easylist?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I'm probably missing something super obvious, but my searching has turned up nothing. I want to put a table in the middle of an outline that I'm making with the `easylist` package. The table is coming right after text that's 2 levels deep, but since `tabularx` centers the table by default, the left edge of the table is about a quarter of an inch left of the text, which looks terrible. My current set up looks basically like this.

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}
\begin{easylist}[articletoc]
\ListProperties(Margin2=.5in,Margin3=1in,Margin4=1.5in)
# Section
    ## Subsection
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X | }
\hline
this & that \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

If somebody can point me towards how to left align the table with a set distance to either the margin or the edge of the page, I can work with that. Bonus points for a way that actually matches it to the level of indentation of the previous text, rather than hard coding the distance.

Comment: tabularx does not centre anything by default. Please edit ypur question to make a complete document showing all packages used that may be run to show the problem.

Comment: Precede your `tabularx` with `\noindent`. This is the default indentation of a paragraph, initiated by `tabularx`.

Comment: Right you are David. I was using the `ltablex` package which appears to be responsible for the default centering. I pretty much stopped using that package for what I originally added it for, but removing it breaks things. Time for another round of troubleshooting. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`easylist` doesn't update `\linewidth` because it uses a very different way to indent lines. You can emulate it by defining a suitable command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sharp]{easylist}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\currlinewidth{\dimexpr\textwidth-\el@TotalMargin\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\hrule
\bigskip

\begin{easylist}[articletoc]
\ListProperties(Margin2=.5in,Margin3=1in,Margin4=1.5in)
# Section
    ## Subsection

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\currlinewidth}{ | l | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X | }
\hline
this & that \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

The `\hrule` is just to show the line width. Of course if you want to put the `tabularx` on the same line as "Subsection", you have to measure the word in advance.

[image]

Comment: It looks like `ltablex` was conflicting (which I forgot to mention I was using), but without it, your code works great. I should be able to remove references to `ltablex` and roll with what you suggested. How do you figure out bits like `\dimexpr\textwidth-\el@TotalMargin\relax`? That's clearly tapping into some abilities I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @Eric I looked into `easylist` and found the parameter that does the analogous thing to `\@totalleftmargin` for the standard LaTeX lists. Some training in LaTeX programming is necessary, but the site is for finding help by trained programmers, isn't it?

Comment: As I dig into it, I'm thinking I really do need to keep ltablex for a different table which does go for more than a page. Any idea how to get that to work? I find I can hard code it with `\setlength{\LTleft}{.86in} \setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}`, but it leaves unnecessary whitespace on top and bottom, as well as needing to be hardcoded. the `\currlinewidth` rule you created seems to be entirely ignored as soon as `ltablex` is added.

Comment: Interestingly, `tabulary` looks to match up with the `easylist` indents by default. I don't really want to use `tabularx` and `ltablex` for the long tables and `tabulary` for the small inset tables since it feels kludgy, but if it works...